# Solving the trigonometric equation $\cos(x)-.4=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find the exact equations (if possible) for $\cos(x)-.4=0$.

I have found the first answer to be $1.159+2\pi k$.  For the second answer, do I have to subtract $2\pi$ and $1.159$ to get the answer? Or do I subtract from $\pi$?

Answer (score 2):

This should be clear from the unit circle:
[image: Cosine is the projection on the x-axis]

You have to find an angle, projection of which on the x-axis is the same. That is $-1.159$ or even better: $2\pi-1.159$ if you want a number from interval $[0,2\pi]$

You can see it even from the plot of cosine - cosine is an even function, which means
$$\cos (x)=\cos(-x)$$
and since cosine is also $2\pi$ periodic, $\cos(-x)$ is the same as $\cos(2\pi-x)$

Comment: Also, I have the equation sin(2x-1)=0.  I know the answer is .5+pik but I don't understand how the answer was derived if the domain for sine must be between (-pi/2 and pi/2).  Also, can you assume that for every sine equation, you only get one answer?

Comment: well you have to substitute 2x-1 for y
so you know, that sin y=0 for y= 0 and pi +2k pi
now you return the substitution and get the answer for x

Answer (score 1):

It's like you've written:
$$ \cos^{-1}(0.4)+2\pi k \; \;  k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
And to get the other solution you subtract $\cos^{-1}(0.4)$ from $2\pi$ therefore:
$$ 2\pi-\cos^{-1}(0.4)+2\pi k =2\pi(k+1)-\cos^{-1}(0.4) \; \;  \text{ for } k \in \mathbb{Z}$$ 
Since $k$ is an arbitrary integer $k+1$ is also just an arbitrary integer so we can write this as:
$$2\pi n-\cos^{-1}(0.4) \; \; n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Therefore the two answers are:
$$ \cos^{-1}(0.4)+2 \pi k \;\; \text{ and } \;\; 2\pi k-\cos^{-1}(0.4)  \;\; \text{ for } \;\; k\in \mathbb{Z} $$

Comment: If this equation was a tangent, would you only add pi to get the second answer? And if it is sine, would you still subtract from 2pi?

Comment: @Erin For Sine you subtract the angle form $\pi$, for cosine you subtract the angle from $2 \pi$ and for the tangent function you just add arbitrary $\pi$ (i.e. $n \pi \;\; n\in \mathbb{Z}$).